# Persistent partial keys in Redis Cache

Tags: redis

I have multiple keys in redis for session management and the lifetime of each key is 10 sec. So, losing these keys are fine for me as I can recreate a session.

However, I have one key, which I cannot afford to lose. Hence I would like that whenever the server restarts, redis reads only this keys from its persistent storage, and keep on persisting these as and when they change.

Is there an inbuilt redis way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, reference
https://redis.io/topics/persistence
redis supports persistence.